# URI Format Not supported error while copying files from one server to another

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to copy list of files from one server folder to another server folder.I need to copy only the files, which of them files name are started with **override**.I get an error **URI Format Not supported**

```
FileFolderPath = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RootFolderPath"];  //+ @"\" + drDevlist["httpusername"].ToString();
tempfilepath = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DomainPath"].ToString() + "\\Temp\\";
string[] txtList = Directory.GetFiles(FileFolderPath);   ---Getting Error here
foreach (string f in txtList)
{

            string fName = f.Substring(FileFolderPath.Length + 1);

            try
            {

                File.Copy(Path.Combine(FileFolderPath, fName), Path.Combine(tempfilepath, fName));
            }


            catch (IOException copyError)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(copyError.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: string[] txtList = Directory.GetFiles(FileFolderPath) while execute this code getting error

Comment: This is the value http://10.2.64.35:83/Load\\45mnluxm3ft

Comment: now i give value like ////10.2.64.35:83/Load\\45mnluxm3ft .but same exception occured

Comment: Sorry friend...now i tried with as you suggested value.but now getting another exception The user name or password is incorrect

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are passing in an invalid path. You need a pass in a path in a format that `Directory.GetFiles` understands.

One of the following two formats will work for you:

```
\\10.2.64.35:83\Load\45mnluxm3ft
```

or

```
\\\\10.2.64.35:83\\Load\\45mnluxm3ft
```